# Click to Enable TextField React

Tags: reactjs

I am displaying tabular data and each cell displays data using a TextField of Material UI (like input field). I want to show all of these TextFields as disabled at first, and enable any of them if they are clicked on. So user would click on the  TextField and field would become available to alter. How can I do that?

Setting the state for field

```
state = {
        button: false,
    }
```

I have the TextField like below:

```
<TextField 
     disabled={this.state.button}
     onClick={this.fieldActivate} 
     name="abc"
```

Activating field

```
fieldActivate(event) {
    this.setState({
        button: true
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**onClick and disabled**

They don"t work together since disabled elements are not clickable. However, you could use something like onMouseOver.

**Callback and Scope**

If you want to define a function for an Event which uses this keyword, you need to either bind this or call the function from an anonymous function.

**Finding the target**

Since you only want one field to be enabled, you need to identify it somehow. Give them keys/ids.

**Example**

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    enabled: -1
  }

  handleMouseOver(id) {
    this.setState({
      enabled: id
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    let inputs = [];
    for (let i=0; i<=20; i++) {
      inputs.push({ id: i, placeholder: 'Input ' + i });
    }
    
    return (
      <div>
        {inputs.map((input) => {
          return(
            <input 
              disabled={this.state.enabled !== input.id}
              type='text'
              placeholder={input.placeholder}
              onMouseOver={(e) => {
                this.handleMouseOver(input.id);
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
input:disabled{
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
state = { currentFocusElement: '' }

...
<TextField 
  disabled={this.state.currentFocusElement !== 'name'}
  onFocus={() => this.setState({ currentFocusElement: 'name' })}
```

The idea is force a re-render when `onfocus`, and change the `disabled` value